# React / MaterialUI - displaying icon in avatar from props

Tags: reactjs

Good morning.   I have seen many examples of displaying of the predefined icons in a MaterialUI Avatar component.  E.g.

```
 h<Avatar>
   <BuildIcon />
</Avatar>
```

but I havent been able to find an example of displaying an icon from a prop field.  For instance, I have a prop that specifies I want the build icon, I thought this would work

```
<Avatar>
    <{prop.myIcon} />
</Avatar>
```

but I get errors.   Does anybody know a nice way to display an icon within an Avatar from props?

thanks
Bill

Answer (score 2):

You can set the icon for the `Avatar` using the `children` property.

### Import MUI components

```
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import BuildIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Build';
```

### Use the Avatar (and Icon)

You can use the `children` property to set the icon

```
<Avatar children={ BuildIcon } />
```

This is an alternative to the traditional child component

```
<Avatar>
  { BuildIcon }
</Avatar>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you pass jsx as prop you have to use only `{prop.myIcon}` 
For example:

```
<SomeComponent myIcon={<YourSampleIcon />} />
```

If you pass component you have to use `<prop.myIcon />` to render icon:
For example:

```
<SomeComponent myIcon={YourSampleIcon} />
```

Hope this helps you.

Edit:

Material-UI has provided tons of icons already in their `@material-ui/icons` package. You can see all MUI icons here: https://material.io/resources/icons/ and import CammelCase icon name from `@material-ui/icons`. For example:

```
// icon name: all_inbox
import AllInboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AllInbox';
```

But there is second approach too. You can import `Icon` component from `@material-ui/core/Icon` and then place icon name in it to display icon:
For example:

```
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon'
...
return <Icon>all_inbox</Icon>;
```

> To get icon displayed you have to add this in your `index.html` file:`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />` to impor `Material Icons` font.

Comment: thank you for your response.  I am probably too much a newbie to know I can extract the answer from your response.  MaterialUI seems to be just another layer of complexity on top of React.   They provide <Avatar> components, <Icon> components but I didnt see anything in their documentation on how to take one of their pre-defined material  icons ( I am looking at <BuildIcon> to start) and reference it by name (e.g., I would stuff the name of the Icon that I want in to the place I want the actual material icon rendered).   I have tried so many variations the past day,..not sure its even possible

Comment: I edited my answer and you can see how to use Material Icons.  Hope this helps you and if so please upvote and then close question by accepting this answer. Thanks